# Worm Gear Efficiency Loss

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I am pairing a worm with a gear to tilt a cantilever load. I need to calculate the torque needed to drive the worm and would like to know the efficiency loss to expect due to the worm. How can I find/calculate the expected efficiency loss? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the gear ratio you can measure the input force and the output force and compare them against each other after accounting for the mechanical advantage. The ratio between the torque you actually got on the output versus the ideal output torque should be the efficiency.

Alternatively browse online for rough estimates of typical worm gear efficiency, which I do not know off the top of my head. It should be no better than 50% though. Worms gears have really bad efficiency.